# Cocos2d-html5-WebGL: Documentation required to learn and develop Cocos2d-html5-WebGL programming

Tags: cocos2d-html5

I am trying to use Cocos2d-html5 framework (v 2.1.x) with WebGL programming concepts to develop 3d application. I am able to see documentation only for Cocos2d-html5 programming, and not finding any tutorials, API documentation and samples to do it further on WebGL programming concepts. I am searching it for a week, but still couldn't find anything. I need to start development as soon as possible on cocos2d-webgl, so could someone please guide me to get documentation, sample and API's.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Cocos2d-html5 just supports 2D models and 2D world. 
We have a 2.5D version which supports 3D models and 2D world, but it is work in progress.

Answer (score 0):

Me too actually. I think there is nothing there yet. Have you any experience with Cocos2d-iphone or Cocos2d-x at all? There is a free pdf book you can download which compares the differences between cocos2d-iphone and cocos2d-html5 step by step. I can't find it right now but do some googling, otherwise you can start with that:
http://code.zynga.com/2013/02/go-multi-platform-with-cocos2d-js/ and get any support you need from cocos2d-iphone.

If you find anything please update the question. )